# Default username/password in preinstalled Ubuntu systems

Tags: software-center, password, sudo, username

I already searched around the web and couldn't find an answer.

These days lots of computers (mainly laptops) come with Ubuntu preinstalled.

Just out of curiosity, what is the default admin username/password? For example, if I want to install something from the Software Center or run a command with `sudo`, what is the password for that?

Does Ubuntu ask you for a username/password in the first boot when it comes preinstalled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default password in OEM installations.

When you start the system for the first time it suggests to set a password.

If you do not get this prompt, it means that someone used the system and has set a password.

You can always reset the administrator password using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/167850).

Comment: Thanks! I always had curiosity on what would happen if I bought a preinstalled Ubuntu machine (and didn't know that it was called OEM, portuguese speaker problems).

Comment: You can install Ubuntu in OEM mode. There is an option in new installers, if I am correct.

Answer (score 3):

Default username: `ubuntu`

Default password: `ubuntu`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this thread useful: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2456500

The default OEM password was password. After that I was able to run "prepare shipment to end user" and finish the setup.

There is also some information claiming that BIOS reset is necessary: https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Dell-recovery-problem/td-p/7889072